# Bumblebee and Intel drivers. Do I need both?

Tags: intel, bumblebee

I have a laptop with Nvidia GeForce 650M and Intel HD 4000. To use the Nvidia card I have already installed Bumblebee. I just found that Intel drivers are also available for 14.04 and I also found that XBMC renders Hi-def videos with a bit of lag if I run it with Intel card (without optirun).
 So, I am a bit concerned that should I install Intel drivers too or will bumblebee do the job?